# Kafka implementation - how to see end to end workflows with microservices

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

We recently implemented Kafka and we are going from a monolothic code base to microservices.  Each consumer of Kafka is it's own microservice.  But now, things are getting a bit unruly.  We have a lot of consumers, and sometimes a consumer will produce an event too and another consumer will consume that event.  The problem is now when somebody asks me to troubleshoot a certain issue, I have NO idea what consumers are subscribed... and I'm unable to have a full end to end view of what's going on without digging into the code of each repo / consumer repo (which we have a lot and it would take too long).

What is something we can do to have an end to end understanding from producers to consumers, etc?  Mainly for troubleshooting purposes / change management.

p.s. we most likely did not implement kafka "the right way" - so don't be shy of stating the obvious

Comment: Does your cluster have authentication?

Comment: the keyword you're looking for is probably 'distributed tracing' https://www.confluent.io/blog/importance-of-distributed-tracing-for-apache-kafka-based-applications/

Comment: Ideally the status of the consumers and topics can be tracked from the JMX metrics exposed by kafka. Im not sure if you have that setup for the cluster. 
You can export the metrics to prometheus and visualize on grafana. Metrics like consumer.lag can help you provide better understanding of youre pipeline. Also Logging is very important in your microservice incase of any bad event it is important to log the event or even pushing the even back to kafka (DLQ) is good. If you provide with some more specific info we can dig into that

Comment: Generally you'll include some form of token with the original request and maintain it throughout all processing. You may also need sub-tokens if there's a hierarchy of inter-service messages. This allows granular introspection of everything involved with a specific process, which can then be traced back to code. There's many ways this could be implemented.

Comment: We're making heavy use of https://www.conduktor.io/ for Kafka management, it's well worth checking out.